# received data from serial port in specific time interval c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

Sorry if this question doesn't make any sense. I am creating a GUI in c# to receive and send data from/to controller. I got stuck at a very weird palace. let say I have send data to controller and controller should send me acknowledgment back. I am handling the acknowledgment. my question is after sending the data I want to raise an error if I did not get anything from the controller.

Comment: it depends a lot on your code, but you could set response=false; just start a timer, after a given time out, if response is still false, raise an exception

Comment: I have a port_receive event to get the data how can I use the timer_click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your port_receive event set a "dataReceived" flag to true. In your timer.Elapsed event handler, if this value is false the data has not been received in time and the error can be thrown. My example below demonstrates something similar, the DataReceived method represents your port_receive method. You can play around with the timer interval and delay to see that if data is received in time the error message is never displayed.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
class Program
{
    static bool dataNotReceived = true;
    static readonly Timer timer = new Timer {Interval = 1000};

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            if (dataNotReceived)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Data not received, error thrown...");
                throw new Exception();
            }
        };

        timer.Start();

        DataReceived();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task DataReceived()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Data received in time");
        dataNotReceived = false;
        timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ReadTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the SerialPort like this

```
SerialPort Port = new SerialPort()
//Define baudrate and so on
Port.ReadTimeout = 1000;
```

Now you could get the TimeoutException by waiting for an answer.

```
Port.Write(Request);
try
{
  //waiting for an answer
  Port.ReadByte();
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{
  //No answer until timeout
}
```